# What is the Charge vigor good for?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I have almost completed Bioshock Infinite's [`1999 Mode`](http://www.ign.com/wikis/bioshock-infinite/1999_Mode) and, at this point, I feel I understand the advantages/drawbacks for each of the vigors.  Well all except for one... the [`Charge Vigor`](http://www.ign.com/wikis/bioshock-infinite/Charge).

*Image provided below* (hidden so it doesn't show other vigors in the game):

> [image: Charge]

I feel I almost ***never*** use this thing. The only time I did was when I first got it... I used it on a swarm of enemies (*probably not a good idea*), got owned, and never used it again. So, is there any real reason to use this? If so, when?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Upgraded charge vigor is broken if you have the right equipment. You want one where you gain health from killing people with melee, 40% chance to gain salts from a killed person, 70% chance to burn the target after a melee hit for 300 damage and use health as salts when you run out.

Answer (score 3):

Well I found a video that perfectly shows how to use the Charge Vigor to your advantage.

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

***UPDATE***: After completing 1999 Mode, I found out just how useful the Charge Vigor actually was.

Not only could I use it to kill the very difficult Lady Comstock (video above), but it was also effective against swarms of enemies and, even Handymen (using Charge dislodges their hand, which causes a 2-4 second animation, allowing for easy heart shots)!

I have also provided a list of suggested gear that work exceptionally well with the Charge Vigor (a complete list of gear: [`here`](http://www.ign.com/wikis/bioshock-infinite/Gear)):

#### Hat:

[image]
[image][image]

#### Shirt:

[image] [image] [image]

#### Pants:

[image] [image]

#### Boots:

[image] [image]

Comment: This is actually a great example, given that other vigors are totally ineffective in this battle.

Answer (score 1):

The Charge vigor can be useful in swarms especially with the Overkill pants, which stuns nearby enemies when you kill an enemy with excessive damage. I found it especially useful later in the game:

> In Comstock house, in case I accidentally alerted a Boy of Silence, since the enemies there were simply swarm enemies, and could be quickly dispatched with charge.

But there are certainly better strategies for that area, especially given the high salt cost. Also, I have never tried it in 1999 Mode, but I imagine its effectiveness would be significantly lower than my experience on Hard.

Comment: "Overkill pants" is not a phrase we get to use very often, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I used the bronco / charge combo quite a lot. This was especially useful against multiple targets. Once they are floating - charge one after another and knock them far, far away.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this Vigor(upgraded) to fully recharge your shield.
I had to use this several times during my playthrough and it helped me quite a bit. As soon as my shield broke down, i charged at someone and had no problems anymore...
Except standing in a crowd of fine gentlemen who want to tear me to pieces...

But nevertheless: No shields + Upgraded Charge = Instant shield!